# Зацикливается while при считывании с клавиатуры?

Tags: java, while, scanner

Подскажите, почему не работает? Если ввести букву, то выход из цикла не происходит. И нужно ли как то закрывать scanner?

```
package n4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class n4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double inputY=0.0;
        boolean numberCorrect = false;
        while (numberCorrect==false){
            System.out.println("Введите число: ");
            if(!(in.hasNextDouble())){
                System.out.println("Введено не число типа double");
            }
            else{
                numberCorrect=true;
                inputY = in.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Было задано число: "+inputY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так сделайте:

```
    Scanner in = null;
    double inputY = 0.0;
    boolean numberCorrect = false;
    while (numberCorrect == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (!(in.hasNextDouble()))
        {
            System.out.println("Введено не число типа double");
        }
        else
        {
            numberCorrect = true;
            inputY = in.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Было задано число: " + inputY);
```

Просто при вводе данных, in читается и потом не обновляется, в связи с чем Вы и получаете бесконечый цикл.

Comment: Спасибо. А Scanner как то надо закрывать, а то он желтеньким подчеркивается Resource leak: 'in' is never closed?

Comment: in.close(); - надо конечно, поторопился прост

Comment: А где его закрывать в этом примере?  И  в конце while пробовал и после while. Опять зацикливается

Comment: Поправил немного код

Comment: Спасибо. В когда его вообще закрывают? У меня программа допустим такая - считываем входные данные с клавиатуры,  формируем из них типа матрицы. Потом обрабатываем эту матрицу. Потом еще немножко данных запрашиваем.

Comment: Ну в целом, лучше закрывать сразу, как прочитаны и сохранены все данные, т.е., соответственно, когда не нужен.